# How to pick a random element in a 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, random, 2d, element

Ok I want to pick a random point in the 2d array so it can be filled. Ive seen how to do this for a 1d array, and am wondering how this would be possible in a 2d array. All I have seen about this method is that the same position comes up again, which is a slight problem, but I don't know how to do it in the first place. The 2d array is essentially a grid, with the dimensions being the x and y coordinates. And the random element selecting a point within the boundaries (which is user selected but for the purposes of this problem can be 30x50.

EDIT:

```
  import java.util.Random;
class pickRand{
public static String get (int x, int y){
    int rndx = generator.nextInt(x) + 2;
    int rndy = generator.nextInt(y) + 2;


}
}
```

So would this work, the x and y will correspond to the user generated number and have a raised boundary of 2 either side to prevent any objects going (partially outside or  of the grid. Nothing needs to be returned right?

Answer (score 3):

If you grid is of size `M by N`

- Generate a random number between `0 and M-1` say **i**
- Generate another random between `0 and N-1`  say **j**

**(i,j)** will be a random element of the 2d array

Comment: this, plus if you want to check if the point is already marked, do the generation in a loop, check if the point with the random generated coordinates is already marked, if yes, repeat, if not, mark and leave the loop

Comment: Alternatively, you can flatten the 2-dimensional array to be a M×N 1-dimensional array. It just leaves you to define whether successive indices increase on the horizontal or vertical axis first. (Some may disagree, but I find 1-dimensional arrays more convenient to work with)

Comment: Or you draw a random number in `0` to `M*N-1` and compute the x and y positions from i. Note that in most languages, 2d arrays can be ragged.

Answer (score 0):

What role does the *array* play here?

Essentially, the task is to pick... **random integer 2D coordinates**.

So if you want two coordinates, say `i` in `0...W-1` and `j` in `0...H-1`, just draw two random integers. If you need more for higher dimensionality, draw more randoms.

Obviously, you can then access `array[i][j]`.

In most languages, arrays can however be ragged, i.e. the rows/columns may have different lengths. This is however just as trivial to handle...